# Saving scores with Pickle

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I'm quite new to python. I have written a program that saves high scores in a pickle dictionary object and then calls it. I have a few questions about my program that maybe someone can help me with.

- How do you store and update this data through multiple app launches? (quitting Python IDLE and reopening it does not save these scores)
- **Solved:** Why does the program write the new score of the same person no matter if its higher or lower?

-

```
import pickle

high_scores = {"Adam Smith": 65536, "John Doe": 10000}
with open("highscores.pkl","wb") as out:
    pickle.dump(high_scores, out)

new_score = (raw_input("Enter your name ").title(), int(raw_input("Enter your score ")))

with open("highscores.pkl","rb") as in_:
    high_scores = pickle.load(in_)
if new_score[0] not in high_scores:
    high_scores[new_score[0]] = new_score[1]
if new_score[0] in high_scores and new_score[1] not in high_scores.values():
    high_scores[new_score[0]] = new_score[1] 
else:
    pass

with open("highscores.pkl","wb") as out:
    pickle.dump(high_scores, out)

print("-" * 80)
for name, score in high_scores.items():
    print("{{name:>{col_width}}} | {{score:<{col_width}}}".format(col_width=(80-3)//2).format(name=name, score=score))
```

Comment: The start of your code overwrites the file every time you run the code - why would you expect changes to last *"through multiple app launches"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe what part overwrites the file?

Comment: Excluding the `import`, the first three lines.

Comment: Really, the answer to both your questions is "because that's exactly what you have told the code to do" - the real question is why you expected a different outcome. You might find it useful to split the code down into smaller functions (e.g. one to read in the file, one to write out to the file, one to take user input, one to update the dictionary, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Padraic's suggestion, the code below checks to see if `highscores.pkl` exists. If it does, then it unpickles the contents into `high_scores`, otherwise the two default scores are assigned to it.

From there, after a new score has been entered, we check to see if the key (player name) exists in `high_scores`. If it does, and the new score is higher then the old score is replaced. If the key does not exist, then we add the player and score.

After that check has been carried out, `high_scores` is saved by writing to the `highscores.pkl` file.

```
import pickle
import os

high_scores = {}

if os.path.isfile('highscores.pkl'):
    with open("highscores.pkl", "rb") as f:
        high_scores = pickle.load(f)
else:
    high_scores = {"Adam Smith": 65536, "John Doe": 10000}

new_score = (raw_input("Enter your name ").title(), int(raw_input("Enter your score ")))

if new_score[0] in high_scores:
    if new_score[1] > high_scores[new_score[0]]:
        high_scores[new_score[0]] = new_score[1]
else:
    high_scores[new_score[0]] = new_score[1] 

with open("highscores.pkl","wb") as out:
    pickle.dump(high_scores, out)

print("-" * 80)
for name, score in high_scores.items():
    print("{{name:>{col_width}}} | {{score:<{col_width}}}".format(col_width=(80-3)//2).format(name=name, score=score))
```

Comment: with open("highscores.pkl", "rb") as in:
gives me an invalid syntax error

Comment: My mistake for changing that without testing. `in` is a reserved word in Python, so just change that and the line after to use something else. For example: `with open("highscores.pkl", "rb") as f:` etc.

Answer (score 2):

*Why does the program write the new score of the same person no matter if its higher or lower*

You don't compare values, you just check if the value already exists.

You would need to check `if new score is > old score` then store it in values.

You need to `load` the object first then do your checks and `dump` at the end or you will overwrite the same data each time you run the app.

```
high_scores = {"Adam Smith": 65536, "John Doe": 10000}
with open("highscores.pkl","wb") as out:
    pickle.dump(high_scores, out)
```

You are overwriting the above data each time you start the app.

You need some logic at the start of your app to check if you have any data already pickled , if you don't, it is the first run so set `high_scores ={}`  and add the updated info, if there is data in it just unpickle and test the stored values against the new.

```
If the file "highscores.pkl" does not exist, high_score ={} else open the file for reading

Do your comparison check and finally pickle.dump to file.
```

Comment: 'You need some logic at the start of your app to check if you have any data already pickled , if you don't, it is the first run so set high_scores ={} and add the updated info, if there is data in it just unpickle and test the stored values against the new.' Can you maybe give me an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

- Use pickle.dump(obj, file) to save it to a file, and obj =  pickle.load(file) to load it. Looks like you've already done that
- Try replacing `new_score[1] not in high_scores.values()` with `new_score[1] > high_scores[new_score[0]]` because the latter one actually checks if the new score is higher than the old one